# Splitting high- and low-freq oscilation and averaging the former

Tags: dynamical-systems, perturbation-theory

I have a system of nonlinear DEs $\dot{x}=f(x)$, where $x=[z_1,\,z_2,\,\phi_1,\,\phi_2]$. The r.h.s. are $2\pi$-periodic in $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, i.e. $f(x)$ contains the terms like $trig(\phi_1)*trig(\phi_2)$, where $trig$ is either sine or cosine.

When I simulate the system I observe a superposition of two oscillations with frequences $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$, $\omega_1 \approx 7\omega_2$. I tried to average over $[0,2\pi]$, but the resulting system turned out to be too coarse. So, I wonder

> Is it possible to separate the high- and low-frequency oscillations
>   and average the system in order to get rid of the high-frequency ones?

I understand that the question can be too broad. If so, I would appreciate any references to the relevant sources of information.

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to transform the ODE somehow to obtain the low-frequency solution, or to manipulate the computed solution to remove the high frequencies. If the latter, you could simply apply a low-pass filter, i.e. take the Fourier transform and zero out the coefficients of high-frequency modes.

Comment: I want to modify the system, not the solution.

Comment: Try the method of multiple scales with two time scales (for the fast and slow oscillations. Good resources include Kevorkian and Cole "Multiple Scale and Singular Perturbation Methods", and Bender and Orszag "Advanced mathematical methods for scientists and engineers".

Comment: @David, thanks a lot!